# Want to make this slideshow repeat

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, settimeout, repeat

i want to ask you how i can make 5 pictures in this slideshow to repeat automatically.Please tell me what i need to change in this code:

```
function SlideShow(Number) {
    document.ShowSlajdova.src=ImageList[Number].src;
    Number +=1;
    if (Number<ImageList.length) {
        window.setTimeout("SlideShow("+Number+")",2000);    
    }
}
<body>
    <img src="1.jpg" width=400 height="200"name="ShowSlajdova">
</body>
```

When this slideshow goes to the last picture it just ends and I don't know how to make it repeat.

Comment: Please include the problem, what you have tried to do to fix it, and any previous questions that you have found that didn't work and explain why they did not work.

Comment: When this slideshow goes to the last picture it just ends and i don't know how to make it repeat. If you know how, please help me.

Comment: You still need to include what you have tried to solve it, but it would also be good to place that problem that you just mentioned in the question itself.  You may want to read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Number<ImageList.length) {
    window.setTimeout("SlideShow("+Number+")",2000);    
} else if(Number>Image.List.length) {
    Number = 0;
    SlideShow(Number);
}
```

Once you reach the end of ImageList, reset the counter and run the function again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the whole function over again. There is a more efficient way to do this than the alternative answer. You can fix this issue by changing the code to look like this:

```
function SlideShow(Number) {
    document.ShowSlajdova.src=ImageList[Number].src;
    Number +=1;
    if (Number<ImageList.length) {
        window.setTimeout("SlideShow("+Number+")",2000);    
    }
    else if(Number>Image.List.length) {
    Number = 0;
    window.setTimeout("SlideShow("+Number+")",2000);
    }
}
<body>
    <img src="1.jpg" width=400 height="200"name="ShowSlajdova">
</body>
```